# Delete confirmation not showing up

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a delete confirmation. I use the following code:

```
<a target="_self" class="style5" onclick="return confirm('ARE YOU SURE TO DELETE <?php echo $student_name; ?>'s FROM OUR DATABASE?')" alt="Delete Data">
<a href="?open=Class-Delete&amp;Kode=<?php echo $Kode; ?>" class="btn-danger style17">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
</a>
```

But the confirmation is not showing up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've updated your answer to break up the lines and increase clarity, but it would appear as though you are using **two** hyperlinks, and not closing your `<span>` tag. This is invalid markup, and may be causing some link errors (which sounds like the cause of your problem). However, can you please also post your relevant PHP so we can confirm the problem isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you have a simple syntax error. If you look at your code here,

`return confirm('ARE YOU SURE TO DELETE <?php echo $student_name; ?>'s FROM OUR DATABASE?')`

You have three apostrophes. This means that when you run it it says "oh so the string is 'ARE YOU SURE TO DELETE ' with FROM OUR DATABASE?' at then end, but that end part doesn't make any sense so I won't do anything"

To fix this, you can escape the apostrophe in the middle by appending '\' to it to make it

`'ARE YOU SURE TO DELETE <?php echo $student_name; ?>\'s FROM OUR DATABASE?'`

It also looks like you have an unclosed  tag and an unclosed  tag. You should definitely fix that up because as Obsidian Age said, it could cause some errors with your markup or mess up with your  tags (linking errors).

Also, you do not need that `return` in there. It is totally useless, and can sometimes cause errors, like when I tested your code using my console. You should remove it, because it may be helping cause the malfunction that you have in your code.

The updated version of your code should look something like the code below, but with the markup fixed.

```html
<a target="_self" class="style5" onclick="confirm('ARE YOU SURE TO DELETE <?php echo $student_name; ?>\'s FROM OUR DATABASE?')" alt="Delete Data">
<a href="?open=Class-Delete&amp;Kode=<?php echo $Kode; ?>" class="btn-danger style17">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
</a>
```

Comment: i have changed it into `<a target="_self" class="style5" onclick="confirm('ARE YOU SURE TO DELETE <?php echo $student_name; ?>\'s FROM OUR DATABASE?')" alt="Delete Data" href="?open=Class-Delete&amp;Kode=<?php echo $Kode; ?>" class="btn-danger style17">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</a>` the pop up is coming out, but when i click cancel, database is still deleted.

Comment: @FortunatusGathot
What is happening is that you need to take the response of the popup and check weather you should delete your database or not.

you can do this by:

`var x = confirm()`

and using an `if()` statement to check for `x`

Answer (score 0):

just add a `\` before `'s` in your code.

```
<a target="_self" class="style5" onclick="return confirm('ARE YOU SURE TO DELETE <?php echo $student_name; ?>\'s FROM OUR DATABASE?')" alt="Delete Data">
<a href="?open=Class-Delete&amp;Kode=<?php echo $Kode; ?>" class="btn-danger style17">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `\` to escape the apostrophe in your string.

change this:

```
return confirm('ARE YOU SURE TO DELETE <?php echo $student_name; ?>'s FROM OUR DATABASE?')
```

to this:

```
return confirm('ARE YOU SURE TO DELETE <?php echo $student_name; ?>\'s FROM OUR DATABASE?')
```